# Layout issues recreating google homepage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the Google homepage but I'm struggling with some issues.

The footer is a bit tall and when I try and add a height figure to it, it makes the screen bigger. Also, it looks like the search buttons overlap the search box. On my browser it looks ok but I'm not sure how to get it to stay below.

How can I achieve that?

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}
ul li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
}
.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#sign-in {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#logo {
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-left: 532px;
  margin-top: 190px;
}
#input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
form input {
  border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  height: 35px;
  width: 550px;
  left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
form input:hover {
  border: solid 1px #aba2a1;
}
form input:active {
  border: solid 0.5px #4285f4;
}
#left.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
}
.Search {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 60%;
  left: 41%;
  border: none;
}
#gs {
  float: left;
}
#lucky {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
button:hover {
  border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}
#left-nav {
  float: left;
}
#right-nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.footer ul {
  color: #757575;
}
.footer ul li {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" img src="http://www.englewoodschools.net/cms/lib8/CO01900647/Centricity/Domain/1009/GoogleAppsIcon.png" alt="google-apps-logo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="sign-in">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo" alt="google">

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="input">
  </form>
  <div class="Search">
    <button type="button" id="gs">Google Search</button>
    <button type="button" id="lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div id="left-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Advertising</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Business</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="right-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Privacy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Terms</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/timmparsons/full/wzNAmO/)

Comment: stop using `margin-left` try use `margin: 0 auto` for centering block-content

Comment: It's look like good, No?!

Answer (score 0):

Change **`.footer`** attributes to `position: fixed` and `height: 40px` to decrease footer height

```
.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  position: fixed; // before: absolute
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px; // before: auto
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}
ul li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
}
.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#sign-in {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#logo {
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-left: 532px;
  margin-top: 190px;
}
#input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
form input {
  border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  height: 35px;
  width: 550px;
  left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
form input:hover {
  border: solid 1px #aba2a1;
}
form input:active {
  border: solid 0.5px #4285f4;
}
#left.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
}
.Search {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 60%;
  left: 41%;
  border: none;
}
#gs {
  float: left;
}
#lucky {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
button:hover {
  border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: black;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
}
#left-nav {
  float: left;
}
#right-nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.footer ul {
  color: #757575;
  margin-top: 3px
}
.footer ul li {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" img src="http://www.englewoodschools.net/cms/lib8/CO01900647/Centricity/Domain/1009/GoogleAppsIcon.png" alt="google-apps-logo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="sign-in">Sign In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo" alt="google">

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="input">
  </form>
  <div class="Search">
    <button type="button" id="gs">Google Search</button>
    <button type="button" id="lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div id="left-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Advertising</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Business</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="right-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Privacy</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Terms</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```